# Программа не заносит значения.

Tags: pascal

В общем, у меня программа должна вносить ответ в [output.txt](http://output.txt), но не вносит. Free pascal

```
assign(input,'input.txt');
reset(input);
assign(output,'output.txt');
rewrite(output);
```

Это в начале, а в конце это все закрывается. Все по правилам. Но после выполнения программы ничего в output не появляется. Почему?

Comment: Покажите код изменения файлов и их закрытия

Comment: А почему там должно что-то появляться? Никаких write тут не видно...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@borealis96](/users/9235/borealis96), конструкция вида

```
assign(output,'output.txt');
rewrite(output);
```

1. Вы ассоциируете переменную с файлом
2. Устанавливаете флаг на перезапись файла (Опустошаете его).

---

```
Rewrite(output);  
Writeln(output,'Hello world');
CloseFile(output);
```

Такая конструкция будет работать и заносить информацию в файл.

Comment: >> Но после выполнения программы ничего в output не появляется  

Это может быть как раз, если не делать "CloseFile(output);"

Comment: @teanЫЧ Не должно бы. По завершению программы система должна файлы закрывать и операции ввода-вывода завершать.